# Java Default browser name

Tags: java, browser

I want to check what default browser is set on computer (name in string). I googled somewhat and i know how to open browser, but i need to check what program will be opened then. How to do this?

Comment: I expect the method for determining the default browser is probably different for each operating system. What operating system are you interested in?

Comment: I would prefer Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information is in the [windows registry](https://superuser.com/a/571854/481513) key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice\Progid`. You can read the key [with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62289/4472840).